# Nested filter with a conditional statement, that's not showing up like i intend

Tags: javascript, nested, conditional-statements

```
function destroyer(...arr) {
    let org = arr[0];
    let cut = arr.splice(1,);
    let result = [];
    let des = org.filter( v =>
        cut.filter( j => {
            if (v == j) {
                false
            }
            else {
                result.push(v)
            }
        })
    )

    console.log(result)
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 2, 3],4, 2, 3)
```

ok So I'm learning online how to do "intermediate" problem, and i'm not sure why this isn't working. 
i though to break up the initial array to be destroyed, into two parts org and cut. i need to delete any values in org that show up in cut. So i nest filter in a filter, set the v and j that match to be false and pushed what wasn't and i got. [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3]

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `,4, 2, 3` are not included in your `arr` variable

Comment: I would expect this method should use the `arguments` variable to get the parameters off of it.

Comment: Or actually it looks like you can do just `function destroyer(org, ...cut) {`

Comment: You are also not using filter properly.  You're not using the `des` variable you are making, and the logic in the inner filter is never returning true or false.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is remove the values outside of the array, from the array, then that should be a simple usage of a filter.

```js
function destroyer( org, ...cut ) {
  let result = org.filter( v => cut.indexOf( v ) < 0 );
  
  console.log( result );
}

destroyer( [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 ], 4, 2, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. U actually showed me a few new things i didn't know, like putting the "org and cut" as the arguments. and the code u recommended is really clean and functional thanks